# does c++ standard prohibit the void main() prototype?

Tags: c++, standards, program-entry-point

In section 3.6.1.2 of both C++ Standard 1998 and 2003 editions,

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
>   have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

I am not a native English speaker.I do not sure what does"but otherwise" means.Whether it is to prohibit the other return type,or to give the right to C++ compiler writer?

So what's the answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The english you quote does prohibit declaring `main` to return `void`. It is allowing variation in the arguments that come in, but not in the return type.

Comment: This is a favorite item to catch for participants in the newsgroups.  However, can one cast the return type of `main` to `void`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your question. Where would you be in a position to be  receiving the return type of main?

Comment: @bmargulies: in another C program that took the first program's result as input? Still, weird question.

Comment: @bmargulies, `main` could be a recursive function, or could be called by some other part of the program.

Comment: @Kevin are you sure main() can be recursive in standard C / C++? Also, where else in a program could you call main from in C / C++? This is not Java.

Comment: @Adriano, good catch, +1 to you.  Recursive main is legal C but specifically illegal C++ (although I've used compilers that allowed it), and this is a C++ question.

Answer (score 7):

Aaargh! Yes it does. The only return type allowed by the standard is int. To quote from section 3.6.1:

> It shall have a return type of type
>   int, but otherwise its type is
>   implementation-defined.

meaning it could look like this:

```
int main( float f );
int main( int x, int y );
```

etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

The type contains more than just the return type. Hence, the return type must be int, but you are free considering the remaining argument, i.e. you may e.g., select between

```
int main()
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: or int main( int argc, char ** argv, char** env) on linux

Comment: But probably a requirement of the compiler.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't forbid additional arguments (although the two signatures you quote must be allowed), so Caspin is correct on some compilers.  It does forbid `void main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is saying that the return type must be `int`, but that the rest of the type is up to the implementation.  For example, you could make a standard-compliant (but not terribly useful) C++ compiler that used.

```
int main(int secondsSinceSystemStart, int myFavoriteNumber, char* aFunnyJoke)
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B):

> In C and C++, the function prototype of the main function looks like one of the following:
>
> ```
> int main(void)
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> ```
>
> The parameters argc, argument count, and argv, argument vector, respectively give the number and value of the program's command-line arguments. The names of argc and argv may be any valid identifier, but it is common convention to use these names. Other platform-dependent formats are also allowed by the C and C++ standards; for example, Unix (though not POSIX.1) and Microsoft Visual C++ have a third argument giving the program's environment, otherwise accessible through getenv in stdlib.h:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
> ```
>
> Mac OS X and Darwin have a fourth parameter containing arbitrary OS-supplied information, such as the path to the executing binary:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as parameters are concern ,it allows

1. int main()
2. int main(int argc , char * argv[])
3. int main(int argc , char * argv[] , char * envr[])

But as per standard return type should be **int** for consistency purpose.

Comment: Number 3 is not required by the C++ Standard.

Comment: The third is allowed but not required by the C++ Standard, along with infinitely many other possible signatures.  The first and second must be allowed by a conforming compiler.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the standard allows main to take any set of parameters beyond the first two, but accessing any further parameters will either be implementation-defined behavior (if the implementation defines them) or Undefined Behavior (if it does not?)

Answer (score 0):

The intent is to say that aspects of the type of the `main` function other than the return type are implementation defined.  That means this declaration is allowed by this clause of the standard:

```
int main(int fred, char *bouncy);
```

but not this one:

```
void main(int fred, char *bouncy);
```

Its return type **must** be `int`, but the implementation is allowed to have different argument types.