# main can't be void

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does c++ standard prohibit the void main() prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915659/does-c-standard-prohibit-the-void-main-prototype)

Why is C++ not letting me do `void main()`? It's not much of a problem, but I'm still curious.

Comment: what's the issue with int void() { return 0;}; ?

Comment: Same as [
does c++ standard prohibit the void main() prototype?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915659/does-c-standard-prohibit-the-void-main-prototype).

Comment: better question is why you're using bloodshed c++ ;)

Comment: Why are you trying to do `void main()?` It's not `void`, it's `int`. Just how it is. You won't even notice the difference, since you don't need an explicit return value anyway.

Comment: If it's your only worry with the language, you've not used it enough. Most arbitrary decisions boil down to: it was simpler this way.

Comment: @Max: and it's the only function with non-void return which can omit the return statement! so `int main(){}` is even shorter by one character!

Comment: The myth of `void main()` seems to be inherited from Herbert Schildt's notorious writings on C, most remarkably in the annotated standard, where the annotations claim its allowed right beside the bit of the standard that says it isn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because return type of `main()`(as mandated by the Standard) must be `int`

C++03 [`Section 3.6.1`  Main function]

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function.  This function shall not be overloaded.  **It shall have  a  return  type  of  type int**,  but  otherwise  its  type  is  implementation-defined.

Answer (score 8):

Answer from **Stroustrup** himself:

Can I write "void main()"?
The definition

```
void main() { /* ... */ }
```

is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C. See the ISO C++ standard 3.6.1[2] or the ISO C standard 5.1.2.2.1. A conforming implementation accepts

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

A conforming implementation may provide more versions of main(), but they must all have return type int. The int returned by main() is a way for a program to return a value to "the system" that invokes it. On systems that doesn't provide such a facility the return value is ignored, but that doesn't make "void main()" legal C++ or legal C. Even if your compiler accepts "void main()" avoid it, or risk being considered ignorant by C and C++ programmers.

In C++, main() need not contain an explicit return statement. In that case, the value returned is 0, meaning successful execution. For example:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This program returns the integer value 0\n";
}
```

Note also that neither ISO C++ nor C99 allows you to leave the type out of a declaration. That is, in contrast to C89 and ARM C++ ,"int" is not assumed where a type is missing in a declaration. Consequently:

```
#include<iostream>

main() { /* ... */ }
```

is an error because the return type of main() is missing.

Source: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Answer (score 4):

Because the standard says that it returns int.

Answer (score 1):

Some operating systems expect an integral return value from processes. Declare main to return an int. If you don't care about the value, simply return 0.

From the comp.lang.c FAQ:

- ["What's the correct declaration of main?"](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html) (There are two: no args, and argc/argv.)
- [Can I declare main as void, to shut off these annoying ``main returns no value'' messages?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html) (Short answer: No)

Comment: You don't even need to return anything explicitly.