# std::map values lost after returning

Tags: c++, dictionary

How to handle memory properly while passing a map from one function to another.

I have a function that returns a map that it builds. The value object is a Class foo. 
I print foo at three different locations, and all of them give different values. The first time, it gives the right values. The second and third are garbage.

I know I have to make the Foo object pointers at the right places.

I want to know where?

```
std::map<int,Foo*> function_that_returns_the_map(){

  std::map<int,Foo*> myMap; 

  {

    int v = 0; 
    Foo *b = new Foo();

    // PRINTING FOO FIRST

    std::cout<<""<<*b<<endl;

    myMap.insert(std::pair<int,Foo*>(v,b))

  }

  // PRINTING FOO AGAIN 

  for(map<int,Foo*>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
  it != myMap.end(); ++it)
  {      
    std::cout << " " << *(it->second) << "\n";
  }


  return myMap;
  }

std::map<int, Foo*> myMap;
myMap = function_that_returns_the_map();

//PRINTING FOO AGAIN.

 std::map<int, Board*>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
 for (it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); ++it)
   cout<<" "<<*(it->second)<<endl;
```

[Click here](http://ideone.com/7kE5rL) to see my actual code.

Update: The member variables of Foo were not being allocated using the 'new' operator. Hence, they were going out of scope and having garbage values once they went out of scope.

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates the problem without modification. Do you realise that you're not actually putting `b` into the map?

Comment: Maybe you want `myMap.insert(std::make_pair(v, b))`. Don't forget to free the memory.

Comment: What do you mean you "print foo"? You can't print a class. Please show the actual code which prints instead of comments.

Comment: @JBentley I have overload the << operator. That prints the members of the class.

Comment: I have edited my comment, to request code. Like I said, you can't print a class, so saying "I print foo" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does it fail if you replace your Foo class with int?  It would be helpful, as others have said, if you edited this to be a complete self-contained example that we could compile and run.

Comment: The functions are in different files, and these files have dependencies. Giving something that you can compile is hence difficult. I wish I could.

Comment: @JBentley I have added the code that prints.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious also as to why you're trying to limit the scope of `v` and `b` by placing them inside a brace block?

Comment: @JBentley There are four instances of objects that are created. Each one is created depending on a condition. All these objects are added to the map. So, the scope is provided by the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had quite a few minor mistakes in your code (which I assume to just be typos). I've fixed those and provided a `Foo` class, and it compiles and runs fine, printing the correct value in all three places:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Foo
{
   Foo() : someValue(5) {};
   int someValue;
};

std::map<int,Foo*> function_that_returns_the_map()
{
   std::map<int,Foo*> myMap;
   {
      int v = 0; 
      Foo *b = new Foo();
      std::cout << (*b).someValue << std::endl; // PRINTING FOO FIRST
      myMap.insert(std::pair<int,Foo*>(v,b));
   }

   // PRINTING FOO AGAIN
   std::map<int, Foo*>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
   for(it; it != myMap.end(); ++it)
   { 
      std::cout << it->second->someValue << "\n";
   }
   return myMap;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<int, Foo*> myMap;
   myMap = function_that_returns_the_map();

   //PRINTING FOO AGAIN.

   std::map<int, Foo*>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
   for (it; it!=myMap.end(); ++it)
   std::cout << it->second->someValue << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

[Click here](http://ideone.com/NgieRP) to view the output.

The issue therefore must be in something you haven't mentioned in your question. To be able to assist further, we'll need to see the real code.

Comment: JBentley, Thanks. Your code demonstrates nothing is wrong with the pointers. I am trying to find what's wrong. And once I do, I will mark your answer as right. Meanwhile, I put all the functions involved completely [here](http://ideone.com/7kE5rL). I would appreciate if you can look into it.

Comment: Found the error, I was filling in the values of Foo without using the new operator. Your explanation comment at Orion answer where you said " The Foo object itself is still in memory in the heap, because you created it with new " made me realize I didn't use new to create the array I am storing in Foo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually create the `std::pair` with the right values:

```
myMap.insert(std::pair<int,Foo*>(v, b));
//                               ^^^^
```

Or make use of `std::make_pair`:

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(v, b));
```

Comment: Apologies. I made a mistake in the code. I am in fact, using v and b values. I missed them while rewriting the code.

Comment: My question is: where should I make foo, so that its values are available at the map in the calling function, in spite of the map storing pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Where you've commented "PRINTING FOO HERE" how are you even compiling it? You can't print `Foo` via the `b` local variable in either of those places because it is out of scope. You instead must retrieve the object out of the map

I made the following changes to your code, and it all works fine:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const int Value;
    Foo(int value) : Value(value) // add some kind of identifier to Foo so we can check it's not garbage
    { }
};

std::map<int,Foo*> function_that_returns_the_map()
{
    std::map<int,Foo*> myMap; 

    { // introducing a new scope

        int v = 0; 
        Foo *b = new Foo(98765);

        // PRINTING FOO HERE.
        std::cout << b->Value << std::endl;

        myMap.insert(std::pair<int,Foo*>(v,b));
    } // v, b go out of scope, are no longer accessible

    // PRINTING FOO HERE.
    std::cout << myMap[0]->Value << std::endl; // we can't use v, b anymore, so go fish in the map to find the Foo

    return myMap;
}

void main()
{
    std::map<int, Foo*> myMap;
    myMap = function_that_returns_the_map();

    //PRINTING FOO HERE.
    std::cout << myMap[0]->Value << std::endl; // we can't use v, b anymore, so go fish in the map to find the Foo
}
```

The key is the scoping. Curly braces in C++ mean scope. Any local variables declared inside that scope can't be used from outside it. Hopefully this will help explain it. If not, please comment about anything that doesn't make sense.

PS: Remember, because you've used `new` to create your `Foo` objects, you **MUST** use `delete` somewhere to clean them up, otherwise your program will memory leak. Because of this, people usually don't put pointers directly into maps or lists. Instead, just put a copy of the `Foo` object in (no pointers), or else use a wrapper such as a `shared_ptr` to manage the deleting for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is applicable anymore, since he edited the question with more code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just modified the code to show how I am printing. I am retrieving the values from the map. The curly braces are present to show the scope.

The value that the map points to, is a pointer. Since that allocation goes out of scope with the curly braces inside in the function, doesn't that mean that the value 98765 doesn't exit anymore?

Comment: @srrvnn The curly braces you have added do not *show* scope, they create a new scope.

Comment: @JBentley I added them in the code to show that, that piece of code is in a new scope. I want to know with this scope arrangement, what is the best place to make the objects so that they don't loose the values like they seem to?

Comment: @srrvnn No, only `b` goes out of scope. `b` is a pointer which contains the address to the `Foo` object. The `Foo` object itself is still in memory in the heap, because you created it with `new`, and no amount of scope exits will change that fact until you `delete` it. `myMap` contains a *copy* of `b` (which again, contains the *address* of the `Foo` object, not the `Foo` object itself), because you inserted it there. As soon as you insert it in the map, `b`'s scope becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Orion Your code doesn't compile, for various reasons. Your `main()` function not returning a value is one example.

Comment: @JBentley - Compiled fine for me in msvc :-)

Comment: @Orion Well, if I add in the missing headers `<map>` and `<iostream>`, then I can get it to compile in MSVC too, to my surprise! It shouldn't compile because `void main()` is illegal ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915659/does-c-standard-prohibit-the-void-main-prototype)) and doesn't compile in GCC - [see ideone output here](http://ideone.com/lvV4Yn). Silly non-conforming compiler :)