# Cant understand how to use seekg tellg to achieve the following result

Tags: c++, seekg

As part of a larger program, my task is to read each line of an input file and store the index offset to each line. Later given all the index offsets, I want to be able to go to that position in the file directly and print the line corresponding to that offset. Can someone help me in figuring out what I am doing incorrectly in the following code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream> 
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>    

    void create_index_info(ifstream& myFile, std::unordered_map<size_t, std::pair<std::streampos, size_t>>& map_index_start_end_pos)
    {
        size_t uiLength;
        size_t uiCount = 0;
        std::string line;

        while (getline(myFile, line))
        {        
            start_pos = myFile.tellg();
            uiLength = strlen(line.c_str());

            map_index_start_end_pos.emplace( uiCount, std::make_pair(start_pos, uiLength) );
            uiCount++;                        
        }
    }

    void print_index_info(ifstream& myFile, const std::unordered_map<size_t, std::pair<std::streampos, size_t>>& map_index_start_end_pos)
    {
        size_t uiLength;
        for(auto it = map_index_start_end_pos.begin(); it != map_index_start_end_pos.end(); it++)
        {
            auto res = it->second;

            myFile.clear();
            myFile.seekg(res.first, ios::beg);
            uiLength = res.second;

            char* buffer = (char*)malloc(uiLength * sizeof(char));
            myFile.read(buffer, uiLength);

            for(size_t uiCount = 0; uiCount < uiLength; uiCount++)
            {
                std::cout<< buffer[uiCount];
            }
            std::cout<<"\n";

            free(buffer);
            buffer = NULL;    
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::unordered_map<size_t, std::pair<std::streampos, size_t>> map_index_start_end_pos;
        ifstream myFile("Filename.txt");
        create_index_info(myFile, map_index_start_end_pos);
        myFile.close();

        ifstream myFile1("Filename.txt");
        print_index_info(myFile1, map_index_start_end_pos);
        myFile1.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

The data in the input text file contains the following entries:

9 10 11

8 7 5

67 34 12 45 9

20

The ideal output for the code should be same as the input modulo upto ordering of the lines being printed (I am using an unordered map, so the output need not be printed in the same order as it was fed). However my code is outputting some garbage, mostly characters of the form \x00. Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Why did you open the file in text mode?  Wouldn't you have more success if it was opened in binary mode?

Comment: One problem is that in `create_index_info`, `start_pos ` points at the _end_ of the string you just read.

Comment: Is `myFile` valid after each attempted `read`?

Comment: *Some* garbage or all garbage? Please copy into the question the output from the given input file.

Comment: [`void main()` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915659).

Comment: @L.F.- yes thanks, really bad typo.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm- thanks for spotting that error, is there a way I can get the std::stream position and the line (std::string) corresponding to position simulataneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your program does not compile.
- Why are you using a map? Why a **vector** is not enough?
- Why `getline` and not **`ignore`**? `ignore` is faster and does not allocate memory.

You are probably looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::istream& get_line_idx( std::istream& is, std::vector<std::streampos>& result )
{
  for( std::streampos pos = is.tellg(); is.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' ); pos = is.tellg() )
    result.push_back( pos );
  return is;
}

void print( std::istream& is, std::vector<std::streampos>& pos )
{
  for( auto curpos : pos )
  {
    std::string line;
    is.seekg( curpos );
    std::getline( is, line );
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::streampos> result;
  {
    std::ifstream is { "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
    if( !is )
      return -1;
    get_line_idx( is, result );
  }

  {
    std::ifstream is { "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
    if( !is )
      return -2;
    print( is, result );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ZDF, yeah void main was a really bad typo. I actually need to store the entire line corresponding to each streampos (for my project requirements). In the larger scheme of things, the map is meant to serve as some kind of dictionary in my project, so a vector will not suite my purpose. What would be a safe way to change the is.ignore function in get_line_idx, so that I can read the line corresponding to pos (ending with "\n" delimiter) into a std::string ?

Comment: Just replace ignore with getline(is, line).